# Angular ng-bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In Angular ng-bootstrap datepicker [Site link here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples), in **Range Selection** part while getting the code from **Typecript section** there is one import "**import {after, before, equals} from './tools';**".

From where we can getting this after, before classes?

Where do we get the **tools** file mentioned or from where we can get the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention for the mentioned `tools.ts` file is that utilities located in this file are to be provided by an application developer. For now those are not part of the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) library, but we are planning on releasing similar utilities in the feature.

To make things worse we had a bug in the demo page and it wasn't obvious from where the `tools.ts` file is coming and what is its content. The bug is fixed now and you can see a working example at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

For the reference, the `tools.ts` file contained the following utilities (we've dropped this file in the latest demo version and just inlined utils as part of the demo):

```
const equals = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  one && two && two.year === one.year && two.month === one.month && two.day === one.day;

const before = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
    ? false : one.day < two.day : one.month < two.month : one.year < two.year;

const after = (one: NgbDateStruct, two: NgbDateStruct) =>
  !one || !two ? false : one.year === two.year ? one.month === two.month ? one.day === two.day
    ? false : one.day > two.day : one.month > two.month : one.year > two.year;
```

You can see it all in action in a plunker forked from the demo page: http://plnkr.co/edit/2I13mvvJBSpX9jyG4p5V?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

```
import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-date'
```

This works!!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/datepicker/demos/range/datepicker-range.ts

it appears that it is defined in the datapicker-range. 
however it is not exported from here.

It also appears to be here: 
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/ngb-date.ts

This one is exported as NgbDate, so you should be able to do:

```
import { NgbDate  } from '@ng-bootstrap/datepicker/ngb-date';
...
NgbDate.after
```

you may need to mess with the path a little (but i dont see an index file that pulls it together.

Comment: But adding NgbDate does not help to run the code in my application. So how am i supposed to put Range selection example in my application..? Because all other examples are running perfectly fine. Please suggest.